# rtl88x2bu messages in dmesg

Tags: networking, drivers

My Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS runs pretty fine.
But, I observed a message appearing in "dmesg" periodically - see a sample bellow.

```
[10958.156576] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[10958.156700] WARNING: CPU: 5 PID: 1024 at /usr/src/rtl88x2bu-5.6.1/hal/hal_com.c:11513 rtw_lps_state_chk+0x39/0x42 [88x2bu]
[10958.156701] Modules linked in: uas usb_storage pci_stub vboxpci(OE) vboxnetadp(OE) vboxnetflt(OE) vboxdrv(OE) xt_conntrack xt_MASQUERADE nf_conntrack_netlink nfnetlink xfrm_user xfrm_algo xt_addrtype iptable_nat nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 libcrc32c bpfilter aufs amdgpu amd_iommu_v2 gpu_sched edac_mce_amd kvm_amd ccp 88x2bu(OE) kvm snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_codec_hdmi crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel cfg80211 snd_hda_intel aesni_intel radeon snd_intel_dspcfg crypto_simd snd_hda_codec cryptd glue_helper snd_hda_core snd_hwdep ttm input_leds snd_pcm drm_kms_helper snd_seq_midi serio_raw wmi_bmof k10temp fam15h_power snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi drm i2c_algo_bit snd_seq fb_sys_fops syscopyarea sysfillrect snd_seq_device sysimgblt snd_timer snd soundcore mac_hid binfmt_misc sch_fq_codel overlay iptable_filter ip6table_filter ip6_tables br_netfilter bridge stp llc arp_tables parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables
[10958.156759]  x_tables autofs4 hid_generic usbhid hid pata_acpi r8169 i2c_piix4 pata_atiixp realtek ahci libahci wmi
[10958.156773] CPU: 5 PID: 1024 Comm: RTW_CMD_THREAD Tainted: G        W  OE     5.4.0-81-generic #91~18.04.1-Ubuntu
[10958.156775] Hardware name: To Be Filled By O.E.M. To Be Filled By O.E.M./980DE3/U3S3 R2.0, BIOS P1.00 02/10/2015
[10958.156875] RIP: 0010:rtw_lps_state_chk+0x39/0x42 [88x2bu]
[10958.156879] Code: 54 53 49 89 fc bb 0b 00 00 00 be 04 06 00 00 4c 89 e7 e8 ae 2a f9 ff 84 c0 79 11 bf 01 00 00 00 e8 86 69 fd ff 80 eb 01 75 e0 <0f> 0b 5b 41 5c 5d c3 f3 c3 0f 1f 44 00 00 55 48 89 e5 41 54 53 48
[10958.156881] RSP: 0018:ffffb1590222bc90 EFLAGS: 00010246
[10958.156884] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 0000000000000000 RCX: 0000000000000000
[10958.156885] RDX: ffff90a062b5dfc0 RSI: 0000000055555554 RDI: ffffb1590222bbc8
[10958.156887] RBP: ffffb1590222bca0 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 000000000002a640
[10958.156889] R10: ffffb159000abd98 R11: 0000000000000461 R12: ffffb15900c9d000
[10958.156890] R13: ffffb1590222bd6c R14: ffffb15900ce5000 R15: ffff90a05a1cdbe0
[10958.156893] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff90a062b40000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[10958.156895] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[10958.156897] CR2: 00007ff16db20000 CR3: 00000002ddff0000 CR4: 00000000000406e0
[10958.156898] Call Trace:
[10958.157002]  SetHwReg+0x6ec/0x70e [88x2bu]
[10958.157104]  rtl8822b_sethwreg+0xdec/0xe02 [88x2bu]
[10958.157205]  sethwreg+0x134/0x13b [88x2bu]
[10958.157303]  rtw_hal_set_hwreg+0x19/0x1b [88x2bu]
[10958.157384]  rtw_set_ps_mode+0xf3/0x223 [88x2bu]
[10958.157464]  LPS_Leave+0xd0/0xd7 [88x2bu]
[10958.157566]  rtl8822b_phy_haldm_watchdog+0x16b/0x191 [88x2bu]
[10958.157666]  rtw_hal_dm_watchdog+0x21/0x24 [88x2bu]
[10958.157728]  rtw_dynamic_chk_wk_hdl+0x37/0x52 [88x2bu]
[10958.157791]  rtw_drvextra_cmd_hdl+0x29c/0x46b [88x2bu]
[10958.157883]  ? _rtw_up_sema+0xe/0x10 [88x2bu]
[10958.157944]  rtw_cmd_thread+0x1ba/0x448 [88x2bu]
[10958.158007]  ? session_tracker_cmd_hdl+0x1df/0x1df [88x2bu]
[10958.158014]  kthread+0x121/0x140
[10958.158080]  ? rtw_stop_cmd_thread+0x3f/0x3f [88x2bu]
[10958.158086]  ? kthread_park+0x90/0x90
[10958.158092]  ret_from_fork+0x22/0x40
[10958.158096] ---[ end trace c64e7ef3c483f865 ]---
```

It looks like some kind of "dump" to me, but I can't understand it.

Any ideas?

Is it worth to go "20.04.2"?

20210828, 20:16 :
I did get (sudo dkms autoinstall) driver from https://github.com/RinCat/RTL88x2BU-Linux-Driver and now I have

```
nicolau@mars:~$ sudo dkms status
rtl88x2bu, git, 5.4.0-81-generic, x86_64: installed
```

The driver version is fantastic :

```
nicolau@mars:~$ modinfo 88x2bu
filename:       /lib/modules/5.4.0-81-generic/updates/dkms/88x2bu.ko
version:        v**5.8.7.4**_37264.20200922_COEX20191120-7777
```

(by the way - the syslog "dump" has gone, so I am very very happy)

Comment: All I can see is a bit of data about your rtl88x2ub WiFi adapter. Is it working as it should?

Comment: You have an old rtl88x2bu-5.6.1 driver. Go to github.com and search for a newer driver. Here's one example... https://github.com/RinCat/RTL88x2BU-Linux-Driver

Comment: I have 2 URLs : (a) https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu {version 5.6.1}  (b) https://github.com/RinCat/RTL88x2BU-Linux-Driver {version 5.8.7.4} - is it the same driver ? are they compatible ??

Comment: by the way, what is the correct way to display the driver version ?

Comment: It seems quite clear to me that 5.8.7.4 is newer than 5.6.1. Please try it.

Comment: I did get (sudo dkms autoinstall) driver from https://github.com/RinCat/RTL88x2BU-Linux-Driver and now I have 
```
nicolau@mars:~$ sudo dkms status
rtl88x2bu, git, 5.4.0-81-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Comment: Glad it's working as expected!